# ‘Related products’ option for Foundry theme

Tags: bigcartel

I would like to add a “similar products” or “related products” option to my product pages using the Foundry theme.

Luna, Roadie, Netizen, and Picklejuice all have this option.

Does anyone know a code I can use to emulate this on my theme?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

```
<div id="related_products"> {% for category in product.categories %} <h2>MORE {{ category.name }} PRODUCTS</h2>
        <div class="related_products {{ category.permalink }}"> {% for product in category.products %} <a href="{{ product.url }}" title="View {{ product.name | escape }}" class="product-a"> <img class="product-img" src="{{ product.image | product_image_url size:"medium" }}" alt="Image of {{ product.name | escape }}" /> </a> {% endfor %} </div> {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Adam! This is exactly the feature I was looking for! Additional question: is there a way to set it to a specific number of products that show? I only want to show 4 but it currently shows all the products I offer.